# WooCommerce custom update_meta issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom function that inserts a WooCommerce product but for _price and _stock, it's only seeing the first digit from my form. For example: I have a select field for stock, 1 - 100, and when it updates the product post meta, it only inserts the first digit: If I select something like 25, only 2 is added.

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', wc_stock_amount( $_POST['_stock'][0] ) );
```

Same with the price field:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', '' === $price ? '' : wc_format_decimal( $_POST['_price'][0]) );
```

Comment: First see what you are getting in $_POST, display print_r($_POST) results here.

Comment: It appears to be posting correctly: [_stock] => 30

Comment: Then why do you append [0]. please paste the whole array output here.

Answer (score 0):

Yea stupid oversight, I had the unneeded [0]. Thank you Maha!